# Using scanf and while loop with vector push_back

Tags: c++, c, vector, buffer, scanf

I tried to get integers from user dynamically from one line, expected input will be :

```
1 2 31 4 1
```

Above input is just an example of 5 integers input, user can put any much numbers if he/she want to.

So, I tried to used vector to store those integers dynamically. This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> s;
    int d, b;

    while(scanf("\n%d", &d) == 1)
        s.push_back(d);

    printf("\nLength : %d", s.size());

    return 0;
}
```

But, it didn't worked. Take an example, I input 6 numbers and press enter, my expectation will be, it will show the size of the vector, but instead it's asking me for another input. I can only stop the "input asking" by pressing Ctrl+D.

It came at my surprise that this code work well :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int d;

    while(scanf("\n%d", &d) == 1)
        printf("%d ", d);

    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, is there any different between printf and push_back that make my first code didn't work?

**Note that \n inside scanf is to prevent trailing newline problem.**

Comment: Use `while(scanf(" %d", &d) == 1)`.

Comment: What's the actual _problem?_ For the first I get a length of five. For the second, it prints out the five numbers.

Comment: If you're programming C++, why are you using `printf` and `scanf`? Also, the `"%d"` [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format code skips leading whitespace automatically.

Comment: @paxdiablo my expectation from above code is, when i insert some numbers, like example `31 2 14 3`, when i press enter, it will show the size of vector, but program didnt stopped when i pressed enter, but its waiting for another input

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry for my code's ugliness, it's just c + c++ code throwing out like a spaghetti, and thanks for the new info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your loop, you can't use `scanf` alone in the condition, as then you loop will continue and `scanf` wait for input until you explicitly gives an end-of-file as input.

If you want to continue to use C code, then I suggest you look into [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then extract the values from the string.

Or you can use C++ and use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which you put into an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) which you easily can get the number from and into the vector:

```
std::vector<int> s;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty())
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(s));
}
```

The code above will loop as long as you enter non-empty lines, and fill the vector `s` with numbers from the input.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` does not fail when it reaches the end of a line. When it's looking for a number, a newline character is just whitespace, indistinguishable from the space character or the tab character or any other whitespace character. If you want `scanf` to fail, you need to either terminate your input (via Ctrl-D as you discovered), or enter something that can't be parsed as an integer.

If you want line-oriented input, use a different method. Since you're using C++ anyway, I would suggest `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1):

At first, can you tell us what's compiler are you using, version, etc. (Different compiler may have different behavior).

And I don't know what do you mean about "didn't work"? Do you mean "print something on your console"?

From your code, you're using while loop here, it won't exit until it reads EOF or encounter read error. In your example, it won't hit the *printf("\nLength : %d", s.size());*

```
int main() {
    vector<int> s;
    int d, b;

    while(scanf("%d", &d) == 1) {
        printf("\nLength : %d", s.size());
        s.push_back(d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you move the code in the while clause, you should be able to see the output on your console.

A. If you know the integer number, you can use a for loop with fixed count; or you can try to use getline(cin, string) to read whole line.

B. Maybe you can debug your code when you find something weird.